# Apply spring security only to one page

Tags: java, spring, security

I have a typical security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
    //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

Now spring is asking for a login for everything except of the login page... But how could I make it the other way, so it asks for login page ONLY for the view /index? Od only for a group of endpoints?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
       http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/index").authenticated()//Makes / and /index to be authenthicated
        .anyRequest().permitAll()//Makes any other allow without authentication. Or if you want a group use antMatchers here too.
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly :)