# Spring-security prevents controller from performing the POST without log error message

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Actually the question is an extension of this one:

[Apply spring security only to one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61273204/apply-spring-security-only-to-one-page)

However the issue is a different one:

I have a working application with ("/index"):

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="/send_message" method="POST">
```

which is connected to the Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/send_message")
    public ModelAndView sendMessage(@ModelAttribute Message message, Model model){
        //program logic here
        return new ModelAndView("info");}}
```

AND IT WORKS as it should - the logic is being performed, the mail is sent to the mailbox, everything is fine.

But after I add the spring-security-dependency and add to the configuration:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http

        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin_panel").authenticated()
         .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
;
    }
```

The app works also as expected (the login for admin_panel) is required as it should, so it is also ok, BUT after using the controller send_message i get redirected to the error page:

```
> 2020-04-24 15:26:38.957 DEBUG 17344 --- [nio-8443-exec-3]
> o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST
> "/error", parameters={masked} 2020-04-24 15:26:38.958 DEBUG 17344 ---
> [nio-8443-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest,
> HttpServletResponse) 2020-04-24 15:26:38.967 DEBUG 17344 ---
> [nio-8443-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting
> from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403 //some logs without meaning
> 2020-04-24 15:26:39.058 DEBUG 17344 --- [nio-8443-exec-7]
> o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to
> ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/static/img/"] 2020-04-24
> 15:26:39.060 DEBUG 17344 --- [nio-8443-exec-7]
> o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 304 NOT_MODIFIED
```

Why does adding spring-security cause the issue and prevent the controller from performing the logic?

Comment: You may need to permitAll to all static resources such as images/js/css, etc.

Comment: Static resources are already permitted by the configuration method: 

//Configuration
 //@EnableWebSecurity
 public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  //@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  //some logic
  ;
  }
 
 
  //@Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
   web
     .ignoring()
     .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/img/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/vendor/**", "/scss/**", "/img/**", "/icon/**","/webjars/**");
  }

Comment: So the .antMatchers("/admin_panel").authenticated() means the call to controller send_message needs to be authenticated, which means only users that are authenticated(basically logged in) can call this method. Please remove this line if that endpoint is meant to be called without authentication, or change it to be antMatchers("/admin_panel").permitAll().

Comment: .csrf().disable() solved the problem